# Algorithmic Version of John's Decomposition of Convex Body

Tags: matrices, convex-geometry

While reading textbooks on convex geometry, I heard about [Fritz John](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fritz_John)'s theorem on convex body, which is known as *John's Theorem* or *John's Decomposition*.

(I know that there are many variants, but this version is from Theorem 2.1 in [Löwner–John Ellipsoids](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/documenta/vol-ismp/24_henk-martin.pdf) by Martin Henk.)

**Theorem:** Let $K \subset \mathbb R^n$ be a convex body contained in an Euclidean ball $B_n$. Then the following statements are equivalent:

1. $B_n$ is the unique minimal volume [ellipsoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid) containing $K$.
2. There exist contact points $\mathbf u_1, \cdots , \mathbf u_m \in \mathtt{bd}\ K ∩ \mathtt{bd}\ B_n$, i.e., lying in the boundary of $K$ and $B_n$, and positive numbers $\lambda_1, \cdots , \lambda_m$, $m \geq n$, such that
   \begin{equation*}
   \sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_i \mathbf u_i = \mathbf 0
   \quad \text{and} \quad
   \mathbf I_n = \sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_i(\mathbf u_i \mathbf u_i^T)
   \end{equation*}
   where $\mathbf I_n$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix.

---

I also know that there are upper bound on the number of contact points $m$ -- it's $n(n + 3)/2$ for general convex body $K$ and $n(n + 1)/2$ when $K$ is symmetric in the origin.

I want to apply this famous theorem to my research but I want an algorithmic version of this theorem. How can we actually compute these $m$ contact points from a convex body $K$? Is there any work on the algorithmic version of John's Theorem?

---

***Update:*** After reading the [answer by Joseph O'Rourke](https://mathoverflow.net/a/146886/11361) below, I see that computing the minimal volume ellipsoid is NP-hard. But I'm interested in computing *$m$ contact points* in John's Theorem when the convex body $K$ and the minimal volume ellipsoid $B_n$ are known.

For example, consider $K=[-1,1]^n$ which is a centered cube in $\mathbb R^n$ whose edge length is 2. Then $K$ and a Euclidean ball of radius $\sqrt 2$ has $2^n$ contact points as all the vertices of the cube lie at the boundary of the ball. Once we regard these $2^n$ contact points as vectors $\mathbf u_1,\cdots,\mathbf u_{2^n}$, one can easily see that
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{i=1}^{2^n} \mathbf u_i = \mathbf 0
\quad\text{and}\quad
\sum_{i=1}^{2^n} \mathbf u_i \mathbf u_i^T = 2^n \mathbf I_n.
\end{equation*}
By setting $\lambda_i = 1/2^n$, we see that these contact points satisfy the condition 2 in John's theorem.

But we know that these $2^n$ contact points are too many and we can pick at most $n(n+1)/2$ of them while satisfying the condition 2 by appropriately chosen scaling parameter $\lambda_i$'s. And my question is as follows:

> Given a convex body and ellipsoid in $\mathbb R^n$, how can we pick these $m$ contact points that satisfy the condition 2 in John's Theorem?

or maybe as a starting point,

> Given a cube $K=[-1,1]^n$ and a Euclidean ball of radius $\sqrt{2}$, how can we pick at most $n(n+1)/2$ vertices of $K$ that satisfy the condition 2 in John's Theorem?

Comment: How is the convex body presented to a computing device? It is a polytope or something more general?

Comment: @SergeiIvanov I don't have much background in this field, but I think we can assume that the convex body is represented as a polytope. Maybe, as a starting point, I can assume that the convex body is a cube $(\pm 1, \cdots, \pm 1)\in\mathbb R^n$. Does it make the problem more solvable?

Answer (score 3):

It is NP-hard to compute the minimum volume enclosing ellipsoid of a set of points
(if the dimension is part of the input).
There have been efficient approximation algorithms developed, e.g.,

> P. Kumar, E. A. Yildirim.
>   "Minimum-Volume Enclosing Ellipsoids and Core Sets."
>   *Journal of Optimization Theory and Applications*.
>   July 2005, Volume 126, Issue 1, pp 1-21.
>   ([Springer link](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10957-005-2653-6))

Jiří Matoušek's 2002 book
*Lectures on Discrete Geometry* has a chapter on this topic (Chapter 13:
[Springer link](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/geometry/book/978-0-387-95373-1)).
That is likely among the best sources.